How to write pull-back metric?
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{2,2} = (\mathbb R^{4}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$$
We define the quadric model of anti-de Sitter space as $$\text{AdS}^3 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid b(x,x) =-1\}$$ Let $x \in \text{AdS}^3$, then $T_x \text{AdS}^3 = x^{\perp}$ Now $\text{AdS}^3$ with $g_{AdS^3} = b\Big|_{x^{\perp}}$ is a Lorentzian manifold of dimension $3$.
Let $x \in \text{AdS}^3$, then $x_1^2+x_2^2 -x_3^2 - x_4^2 = -1$, which implies that $x_1^2+x_2^2+1 = x_3^2 + x_4^2$, thus $(x_3, x_4) \neq (0,0)$. Take $x_3 = rcos\theta$, $x_4 = rsin\theta$. Thus $(x_1, x_2, r) \in \mathbb H^2$ where $\mathbb H^2$ is as one connected component of the two-sheeted hyperboloid in Minkowksy space. Therefore, $\text{AdS}^3$ is homomorphic to $\mathbb H^2 \times S^1$ , under the map $f: \mathbb H^2 \times S^1 \rightarrow \text{AdS}^3$, defined by $$f((x_1, x_2, r), e^{i\theta}) = (x_1, x_2, r cos \theta, r sin \theta).$$
Now I want to put Lorentzian structure on $\mathbb H^2 \times S^1$ by defining a Lorentazian metric on it. I want to write the pill-back metric explicitly,
$$(f^*g_{AdS^3})_{(x, e^{i\theta})} = g_{\mathbb H^2} + \cdots$$
But I cannot write. Can anyone please help me?

Write $x_1=\sinh u\cos v$, $x_2=\sinh u\sin v$, $r=\cosh u$. Then $dx_1^2+dx_2^2-dr^2$ pulls back to $g_{\Bbb H^2}=du^2+\sinh^2u\,dv^2$. Next,  $-(dx_3^2+dx_4^2)$ pulls back to $-(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2)$, so $dx_1^2+dx_2^2-(dx_3^2+dx_4^2)$ pulls back to $g_{\Bbb H^2}- \cosh^2u \,d\theta^2$ at $(u,v,\theta)$.
EDIT: I didn't need to introduce the parametric equations; I just thought that would feel more concrete. Remember that $f^*(dx_i\otimes dx_i) = df_i\otimes df_i$. Here $df_1 = dx_1$, $df_2=dx_2$, $df_3 = \cos\theta\, dr - r\sin\theta\,d\theta$, $df_4=\sin\theta\, dr + r\cos\theta\,d\theta$, so
\begin{align*}
f^*\big(dx_1^2+dx_2^2-(&dx_3^2+dx_4^2)\big)  \\ &=dx_1^2+dx_2^2 - \big((\cos\theta\, dr - r\sin\theta\,d\theta)^2 + (\sin\theta\, dr + r\cos\theta\,d\theta)^2\big) \\ &= dx_1^2+dx_2 - (dr^2 + r^2\,d\theta^2) = (dx_1^2+dx_2 - dr^2) - r^2\,d\theta^2\\ &= g_{\Bbb H^2} - r^2\,d\theta^2.
\end{align*}

Thank your answer. can you please advise about how to pullback metric explicitly?

Do you know how to pull back $1$-forms? Then remember that $dx_i^2 = dx_i\otimes dx_i$.

Sir,  if we have $\mathbb H^n \times S^1$ then how we would pull-back the metric? Because, $\mathbb H^n = {(x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb R^{n,1} \mid x_1^2 +\cdots +x_{n}^2 - x_{n+1}^2 = -1}$. Then how we would parametrize it?

You do not need to parametrize. See the edit.
